# Error with GriauleFinger

Tags: c#, fingerprint

Hi everybody I'm developing c# application with fingerprints, but I had this error:

> GrFinger couldn't read the license file.(error -3)

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not Griaule Fingerprint's customer support. You should contact them or read their documentation to solve this issue.

Comment: Make sure you get a Griaule license, one generated by Griaule with the MAC address of the computer you are developing in. I think whether Trial license or full license you must have a license generated by Griaule using a the MAC address of your developer workstation PC.